# Content duplication issue in editor implemented in Vue JS, real time collab with Y.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sockets, editor

In my Vue 3 Js app, I have integrated a markdown editor (https://milkdown.dev/) which users will use to create documents and collaborate on them in real time. Real time collab is implemented by using the Y.js library.

Everything works fine both frontend and backend but one single issue: when you write a document and you leave it there for some time (even just by opening another browser tab and scrolling some websites for a while), the content you've written duplicates.

So if you write:

Hello

After a while, at random intervals, the content becomes

Hello

Hello

and so on (the duplication happens sereval times).

Here's the frontend code below.

documentSocket.ts

```
import { debugPrint } from '@/debug';
import { socketioservice } from './socketioService';


export class DocumentSocket {
  readonly url: string;
  onmessage?: ((event: any) => void);
  onerror?: ((event: any) => void);
  onclose?: ((event: any) => void);
  onopen?: ((event: any) => void);

  binaryType: BinaryType = 'arraybuffer';
  readonly bufferedAmount: number = -1;
  readonly extensions: string = '';
  readonly protocol: string = '';

  readyState: number;
  readonly CLOSED: number = WebSocket.CLOSED;
  readonly CLOSING: number = WebSocket.CLOSING;
  readonly CONNECTING: number = WebSocket.CONNECTING;
  readonly OPEN: number = WebSocket.OPEN;
  // removeEventListener<K extends keyof WebSocketEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: WebSocket, ev: WebSocketEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;

  syncTimer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>|null = null;

  addEventListener<K extends keyof WebSocketEventMap>(
    type: K,
    listener: (this: WebSocket, ev: WebSocketEventMap[K]) => any,
    options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions
  ): void {
    // debugPrint("log", 'DocumentSocket added event listener')
  }
  removeEventListener<K extends keyof WebSocketEventMap>(
    type: K,
    listener: (this: WebSocket, ev: WebSocketEventMap[K]) => any,
    options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions
  ): void {
    // debugPrint("log", 'DocumentSocket removed event listener')
  }


  async initialization() {
    
    //get id from url
    const [_, id] = this.url.split('/', 2);

    this.readyState = WebSocket.CONNECTING;

    socketioservice.appendListen('document:message', (data: Uint8Array) => {
      if(this.onmessage){
        const dataLength = data.length;
        const firstTenHexChars = Array.from({ length: Math.min(10, dataLength) }, (_, index) => data[index].toString(16)).join('');
        console.log(`Received ${dataLength} chars: ${firstTenHexChars}${dataLength > 10 ? "..." : ""}`);
        this.onmessage({ data: new Uint8Array(data) });
      }
    });

    socketioservice.appendListen('document:sync', () => {
      this.syncTimer && clearTimeout(this.syncTimer);
      this.syncTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.onerror && this.onerror('sync');
      }, 1500);
    });

    socketioservice.appendListen('document:connected', () => {
      this.readyState = WebSocket.OPEN;
      if (this.onopen) this.onopen({});

      socketioservice.deleteListener('document:connected');
    });

    try {
      const reply = await socketioservice.emitWithTimeout('document:open', 1000, {
        container: {
          Id: id
        }
      });
      if (!reply?._id) throw 'something wrong'

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      this.close()
      return;
    }


    this.readyState = WebSocket.CONNECTING;
  }

  constructor(url: string) {
    this.url = url;

    this.readyState = WebSocket.CONNECTING;
    // open document and await
    this.initialization();
    
  }

  send(data: Uint8Array): void {
    socketioservice.emitSimple('document:message', data);
  }

  close() {
    if (this.readyState == WebSocket.CLOSED) return;

    this.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSED;

    this.syncTimer && clearTimeout(this.syncTimer);

    socketioservice.deleteListener('document:message');
    socketioservice.deleteListener('document:sync');
    socketioservice.emitSimple('document:close');

    this.onclose && this.onclose(['close', ]);

  }
}
```

milkdown.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!--Roboto-->
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" />
        <!--Material Icon-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" />
        <VueEditor v-if="editorReturn" :editor="editorReturn.editor" />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">

// list of imports

const props = defineProps({
    id: { type: String, required: true },
    simpleEditor: { type: Boolean, default: () => true },
    readOnly: { type: Boolean },
});

const emit = defineEmits<{
    (event: 'usersUpdated', usersIds: Array<string>): void,
    (event: 'connectionError'): void,
    (event: 'connectionDone'): void,
}>();

const userStore = useUserStore();

let collabService: CollabService | null = null;

const documentContentJson = ref({});

const options: any = { WebSocketPolyfill: DocumentSocket, connect: false };

const { t } = useI18n();

let provider: WebsocketProvider | null = null;

function make(root: HTMLDivElement) {
    const _editor = Editor.make()
        .config(ctx => {
            ctx.set(rootCtx, root);
            ctx.set(
                schemaCtx,
                new Schema({
                    nodes: {
                        doc: { content: 'block+' },
                        paragraph: { content: 'inline*', group: 'block' },
                        text: { group: 'inline' }
                    }
                })
            );
            ctx.set(editorViewOptionsCtx, { editable: () => !props.readOnly });
            ctx.get(listenerCtx).updated((ctx, doc, prevDoc) => {
                documentContentJson.value = doc.toJSON();
            });
        })
        .use(nordLight)
        .use(gfm);
    if (!props.simpleEditor) {
        _editor.use(emoji)
            .use(slash.configure(slashPlugin, {
                config: (ctx) => ({ content, isTopLevel }) => {
                    if (!isTopLevel) return null

                    const view = ctx.get(editorViewCtx)
                    if (!view?.editable) return null

                    if (!content) return { placeholder: t('milkdown.slash.placeholder') }

                    if (content.startsWith('/')) 
                        return (content === '/') ? { actions: defaultActions(ctx) } : { actions: defaultActions(ctx, content) }

                    return null
                }
            }))
            .use(menu)
            .use(tooltip);
    }
    _editor.use(clipboard).use(block).use(collaborative).use(listener);

    // .use(history)
    // editor.use(math)
    // editor .use(commonmark)
    return _editor;
};

function initCollablorativeEditor(editor: Editor) {
    editor.action(ctx => {
        collabService = ctx.get(collabServiceCtx);
        // provider.awareness.setLocalStateField('user', { color: '#008833', name: 'My real name' })
        const username = userStore.user.name + ' ' + userStore.user.surname;
        let doc = new Y.Doc({ gc: true });
        provider = new WebsocketProvider('_', props.id, doc, options);
        provider.awareness.setLocalStateField('user', { name: username, id: userStore.user._id });
        provider.connect();
        collabService.bindDoc(provider.doc);
        collabService.setAwareness(provider.awareness);
        provider.awareness.on('update', () => {
            const awarenessIds = Array.from(provider!.awareness.states.values()).map(el => el.user.id);
            const usersIds = [...new Set(awarenessIds)];
            emit('usersUpdated', usersIds);
        });
        emit('usersUpdated', [userStore.user._id]);

        const onSynced = async (isSynced: boolean) => {
            if (isSynced && collabService != null) {
                collabService.connect();
                emit('connectionDone')
                provider?.off('synced', onSynced);
            }
        };

        provider.on('synced', onSynced);

        // ["connection-close", "connection-error", ""]
        provider?.on('connection-error', (ev) => {
            emit('connectionError');
        });
        // provider?.on('connection-close', (ev) => emit('connectionError'));
        // provider?.on('status', (args) => {
        //     const status = args.status as 'connecting'|'connected'|'disconnected';
            
        //     // ctx.set(editorViewOptionsCtx, { editable: () => false });
        // })
    });
};

let editor: Editor;

const editorReturn = useEditor(root => {
    editor = make(root);
    return editor;
});

onMounted(() => {
    initCollablorativeEditor(editor);
    // setTimeout(() => printSchemaNodesDebug(editor, {marks:true, nodes:true}), 1000);
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    if (collabService) {
        collabService.disconnect();
        collabService = null;
    }
    if (provider) {
        provider.disconnect();
        provider.doc.destroy();
        provider.destroy();
        provider = null;
    }
    emit('usersUpdated', []);
});


defineExpose({
    getDocumentContentJson: () => documentContentJson.value,
});


</script>
```

And here's the backend receiving document data:

documents.ts

```
// List of imports


const docs:Map<string,WSSharedDoc> = new Map();

const messageSync = 0;
const messageAwareness = 1;

class WSSharedDoc extends Y.Doc {
  docId:string;
  // mux: mutex.mutex;
  conns: Map<Socket, Set<number>>;
  
  awareness: awarenessProtocol.Awareness;

  saveTimer: NodeJS.Timeout|null;

  syncInterval: ReturnType<typeof setInterval>;

  saveDone:Boolean = false;
  saveDonePromise?:Promise<void>;

  constructor (docId:string, gcEnabled=false) {
    super({ gc: gcEnabled })

    this.docId = docId
    this.conns = new Map() //Maps from conn to set of controlled user ids. Delete all user ids from awareness when this conn is closed
    
    this.awareness = new awarenessProtocol.Awareness(this)
    this.awareness.setLocalState(null)

    this.saveTimer = null;


    this.syncInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.conns.forEach((_, socket) => socket.emit('document:sync'))
    }, 500);
    
    const awarenessChangeHandler = (changes: { added:Array<number>, updated:Array<number>, removed:Array<number>}, socket:Socket) => {
      const changedClients = changes.added.concat(changes.updated, changes.removed)
      if (socket !== null) {
        const connControlledIDs = this.conns.get(socket)
        if (connControlledIDs !== undefined) {
          changes.added.forEach(clientID => { connControlledIDs.add(clientID) })
          changes.removed.forEach(clientID => { connControlledIDs.delete(clientID) })
        }
      }
      // broadcast awareness update
      const encoder = encoding.createEncoder()
      encoding.writeVarUint(encoder, messageAwareness)
      encoding.writeVarUint8Array(encoder, awarenessProtocol.encodeAwarenessUpdate(this.awareness, changedClients))
      const buff = encoding.toUint8Array(encoder)
      this.conns.forEach((_, c) => {
        send(this.docId, c, buff)
      })
    }
    this.awareness.on('update', awarenessChangeHandler)
    this.on('update', (update, origin, doc) => this.updateHandler(update, origin, doc));
  }

  updateHandler(update:Uint8Array, origin, doc:WSSharedDoc){
    const encoder = encoding.createEncoder()
    encoding.writeVarUint(encoder, messageSync)
    syncProtocol.writeUpdate(encoder, update);
    
    const message = encoding.toUint8Array(encoder)
    doc.conns.forEach((_, socket) => {
      send(doc.docId, socket, message)
    });

    if (doc.saveTimer != null) clearTimeout(doc.saveTimer);
    doc.saveTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      doc.saveInDb();
      doc.saveTimer = null;
    }, 2000);
  }

  async saveInDb(){
    if (!this.saveDone) await this.saveDonePromise;

    const document = yDocToProsemirrorJSON(this);

    this.saveDone = false;
    let res:((value: void | PromiseLike<void>)=>void) = (val) => {} ;
    let rej:(reason?: any) => void;
    this.saveDonePromise = new Promise((_res, _rej) => { res = _res; rej = _rej });
    try {
      await iContainer.updateOne({_id:this.docId}, {document});
    } finally {
      res();
    }
    this.saveDone = true;
  }

  async deleteMe() {
    clearInterval(this.syncInterval)
    this.awareness.destroy();
    this.destroy();
    if (this.saveTimer != null) await this.saveInDb();
    
    docs.delete(this.docId);
  }
}

function send(docId:string, socket:Socket, m:Uint8Array) {
  const doc = docs.get(docId);
  if (!doc) return;

  if (!socket?.connected) {
    closeConnection(doc.docId, socket)
  }
  try {
    const arr = new Uint8Array(m);
    socket.emit('document:message', arr);
  } catch (e) {
    closeConnection(doc.docId, socket)
  }
}

function messageListener(socket:Socket, docId:string, message:Uint8Array) {
  if (!docs.has(docId)) return;
  const doc = docs.get(docId)!;

  try {
    const encoder = encoding.createEncoder()
    const decoder = decoding.createDecoder(message)
    const messageType = decoding.readVarUint(decoder)

    switch (messageType) {
      case messageSync:
        encoding.writeVarUint(encoder, messageSync)
        syncProtocol.readSyncMessage(decoder, encoder, doc, socket.id);
        if (encoding.length(encoder) > 1) {
          send(docId, socket, encoding.toUint8Array(encoder))
        }
        break
      case messageAwareness: {
        awarenessProtocol.applyAwarenessUpdate(doc.awareness, decoding.readVarUint8Array(decoder), socket.id)
        break
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    doc.emit('error', [err])
  }
}
  
  
async function startWSDoc(Id: string, socket:Socket){
  // looks for a document inside the db and creates a local copy
  const doc = await getYDoc(Id, true); //gc);

  // conns is a map <socket, users>
  doc.conns.set(socket, new Set())

  // listen and reply to events
  socket.on('document:message', async (message:Uint8Array) => messageListener(socket, doc.docId, new Uint8Array(message)));
  socket.on('document:close', async () => closeConnection(doc.docId, socket));
  // put the following in a variables in a block so the interval handlers don't keep in in scope
  
  // send sync step 1
  const encoder = encoding.createEncoder()
  encoding.writeVarUint(encoder, messageSync)
  syncProtocol.writeSyncStep1(encoder, doc)
  const buff =  encoding.toUint8Array(encoder);
  send(doc.docId, socket, buff)


  const awarenessStates = doc.awareness.getStates()
  if (awarenessStates.size > 0) {
    const encoder = encoding.createEncoder()
    encoding.writeVarUint(encoder, messageAwareness)
    encoding.writeVarUint8Array(encoder, awarenessProtocol.encodeAwarenessUpdate(doc.awareness, Array.from(awarenessStates.keys())))
    send(doc.docId, socket, encoding.toUint8Array(encoder))
  }

  socket.emit('document:connected');
}
  
export async function openADocument(sessionCtx:SessionContext, ioContext: IOContext){
  const { Id } = ioContext.request.payload.container;
  if (!Id) throw '_id required';

  const page = await iContainer.findById({_id: Id, type: 'page', ...filter_userHasAnyPermissionOnContainer}).select('_id permissions') as Pick<iContainerType, '_id'|'permissions'> | null;
  if (!page) throw 'invalid container!!!!'
  // const ICanWrite = sessionCtx.spaceHandler?.isAdmin(sessionCtx._user) || page.permissions.some(x => x._user.toString() == sessionCtx._user.toString() && x.type == 'w');

  startWSDoc(Id, sessionCtx.socket);

  return {
    _id: page._id.toString()
  }

}

const getYDoc = async (documentId:string, gcEnabled?:boolean):Promise<WSSharedDoc> => {
  if (docs.has(documentId)){
    return docs.get(documentId)!;
  }else {
    const doc = new WSSharedDoc(documentId, gcEnabled);
    docs.set(documentId, doc);

    const container:iPageType|null = await iContainer.findById(documentId)
    if (container?.document) {
      try{
        const _ydoc = prosemirrorJSONToYDoc(milkdownSchema, container.document);
        const _update = Y.encodeStateAsUpdate(_ydoc);
        _ydoc.destroy();
        Y.applyUpdate(doc, _update, 'db');
      }catch{
        doc.getXmlFragment('prosemirror')
      }
    }
    // debugDocs();
    return doc;
  }

}




function closeConnection (docId:string, socket:Socket) {
  const doc = docs.get(docId);
  if (!doc) return;

  if (doc.conns.has(socket)) {
    const controlledIds:Set<number> = doc.conns.get(socket)!

    doc.conns.delete(socket)
    awarenessProtocol.removeAwarenessStates(doc.awareness, Array.from(controlledIds), socket.id)
    if (doc.conns.size === 0) {
      doc.deleteMe();
    }
  }

  socket.removeAllListeners('document:message');
  socket.removeAllListeners('document:close');
}


export function closeAllDocuments(socket:Socket) {
  const docIds:Array<string> = [];
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    if (doc.conns.has(socket)){
      docIds.push(doc.docId);
    }
  });

  for(let docId of docIds){
    closeConnection(docId, socket);
  }
}






const milkdownSchema = new Schema({
  nodes: { "doc": { "content": "block+" }, "paragraph": { "content": "inline*", "group": "block" }, "hardbreak": { "group": "inline", "inline": true, "selectable": false }, "blockquote": { "content": "block+", "group": "block", "defining": true }, "fence": { "content": "text*", "marks": "", "group": "block", "attrs": { "language": { "default": "" }, "fold": { "default": true } }, "code": true, "defining": true }, "bullet_list": { "content": "listItem+", "group": "block" }, "ordered_list": { "content": "listItem+", "group": "block", "attrs": { "order": { "default": 1 } } }, "list_item": { "content": "paragraph block*", "group": "listItem", "attrs": { "label": { "default": "•" }, "listType": { "default": "bullet" } }, "defining": true }, "heading": { "content": "inline*", "group": "block", "attrs": { "id": { "default": "" }, "level": { "default": 1 } }, "defining": true }, "hr": { "group": "block" }, "image": { "marks": "", "group": "inline", "inline": true, "atom": true, "attrs": { "src": { "default": "" }, "alt": { "default": null }, "title": { "default": null } }, "selectable": true, "draggable": true, "defining": true, "isolatin": true }, "text": { "group": "inline" }, "table": { "content": "table_row+", "group": "block", "isolatin": true }, "table_row": { "content": "(table_cell | table_header)*" }, "table_cell": { "content": "paragraph", "attrs": { "colspan": { "default": 1 }, "rowspan": { "default": 1 }, "colwidth": { "default": null }, "alignment": { "default": "left" } }, "isolatin": true }, "table_header": { "content": "paragraph", "attrs": { "colspan": { "default": 1 }, "rowspan": { "default": 1 }, "colwidth": { "default": null }, "alignment": { "default": "left" } }, "isolatin": true }, "task_list_item": { "content": "paragraph block*", "group": "listItem", "attrs": { "checked": { "default": false } }, "defining": true }, "footnote_reference": { "group": "inline", "inline": true, "atom": true, "attrs": { "label": { "default": "" } } }, "footnote_definition": { "content": "block+", "group": "block", "attrs": { "label": { "default": "" } }, "defining": true }, "emoji": { "group": "inline", "inline": true, "atom": true, "attrs": { "html": { "default": "" } } } },
  marks: { "code_inline": { "inclusive": false }, "em": {}, "strong": {}, "link": { "attrs": { "href": {}, "title": { "default": null } }, "inclusive": false }, "strike_through": {} },
})

const simpleMilkdownSchema = new Schema({
  nodes: {
      doc: {
          content: "block+"
      },
      paragraph: {
          content: "inline*",
          group: "block"
      },
      hardbreak: {
          group: "inline",
          inline: true,
          selectable: false
      },
      // blockquote: {
      //     content: "block+",
      //     group: "block",
      //     defining: true
      // },
      // fence: {
      //     content: "text*",
      //     marks: "",
      //     group: "block",
      //     attrs: {
      //         language: {
      //             default: ""
      //         },
      //         fold: {
      //             default: true
      //         }
      //     },
      //     code: true,
      //     defining: true
      // },
      bullet_list: {
          content: "listItem+",
          group: "block"
      },
      ordered_list: {
          content: "listItem+",
          group: "block",
          attrs: {
              order: {
                  default: 1
              }
          }
      },
      list_item: {
          content: "paragraph block*",
          group: "listItem",
          attrs: {
              label: {
                  default: "•"
              },
              listType: {
                  default: "bullet"
              }
          },
          defining: true
      },
      heading: {
          content: "inline*",
          group: "block",
          attrs: {
              id: {
                  default: ""
              },
              level: {
                  default: 1
              }
          },
          defining: true
      },
      // hr: {
      //     group: "block"
      // },
      text: {
          group: "inline"
      },
      // footnote_reference: {
      //     group: "inline",
      //     inline: true,
      //     atom: true,
      //     attrs: {
      //         label: {
      //             default: ""
      //         }
      //     }
      // },
      // footnote_definition: {
      //     content: "block+",
      //     group: "block",
      //     attrs: {
      //         label: {
      //             default: ""
      //         }
      //     },
      //     defining: true
      // },
  },
  marks: {
      code_inline: {
          inclusive: false
      },
      em: {},
      strong: {},
      link: {
          attrs: {
              href: {},
              title: {
                  default: null
              }
          },
          inclusive: false
      },
      strike_through: {}
  },
});
```

I'd love for a fresh pair of eyes to look at this as I have been analysing this for days and can't seem to spot where the issue is. Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: here's the stack trace obtained by setting a breakpoint on the event document:open

```
(anonymous) (documentSocket.ts:73)
(anonymous) (tslib.es6.js:76)
__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:72)
initialization (documentSocket.ts:42)
DocumentSocket (documentSocket.ts:95)
setupWS (y-websocket.js:131)
setTimeout (async)
websocket.onclose (y-websocket.js:171)
close (documentSocket.ts:114)
eval (y-websocket.js:374)
```

Comment: It's hard to find out the mistake without a runtime debugger. Have you tried to debug the code to identify which method is falty (is the socket event received twice? Is it only the writting method called without events?)?

Comment: Hi @Kapcash, the socket event is not received twice, mots of the times it looks like there's no event happening when the content duplicates. Sometimes the console log registers the firing of the event document:open right before the content duplicates, sometimes it doesn't. I will look into improving my debugging further. If you have any suggestion feel free to let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have updated the question with a stacktrace.